# how to scroll control to the top of screen

Tags: jquery

How do I scroll (ideally smooth scroll) down such that the specified control is at the top of the screen? (ie, how do I bring the screen down to the comment section such that the 'comments' title is at the top of the screen?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(something).offset().top });
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`ScrollTo` plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/).

Answer (score 0):

Find here a solution: http://blog.freelancer-id.com/index.php/2009/03/26/scroll-window-smoothly-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

There is a [ScrollTo plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo), that is pretty popular. With this is it simple, just:

```
$.scrollTo(...);
```